# Unable to sync the Quorum’s IBFT private chain with the Faucet

Tags: quorum, faucets, ibft

I am trying to build a faucet to use on the IBFT private chain.

I'm testing whether it can be launched locally by peering it with an already operational private network.
I have been able to launch the API, but the faucet's structure is not updating, causing a 'Faucet offline' error on the front end.

I suspect the loop function is not working properly, but the same logic applies to the latest branches of BSC and quorum, so there may be other reasons.
https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum/blob/a718daa674a2e23cb0c8a6789f7e5467e705bbbd/cmd/faucet/faucet.go#L591-L628

What could be the possible issues?

OS: macOS 12.3.1
goquorum version: 1.9.7